# Trying to implement very simple points simple in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

See the following code in my controller

```
def create
        @wad = current_user.wads.build(wad_params)
        if @wad.save
            current_user.points == current_user.points + 5
            redirect_to @wad    
        else
            flash[:error] = 'Error try again'
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

My goal is that when a user creates a wad they get 5 points. I migrated a points column to the user table fine and am able to update points through the console.

I don't get any errors at all, wads are being created as usual, and the page redirects correctly but the points value is not being updated in the user table. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: `==` is a logical comparison. Try `=`. You also might need to `.save` current_user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of points here:

Firstly, changes to your `user` aren't persisted at the moment as you're not saving either record.

Additionally, you'll need to use a single `=` to assign the user's `points`, or a method as in the following example. The following code will overcome this:

```
def create
  @wad = current_user.wads.build(wad_params)
  if @wad.save
    current_user.update_attributes(points: current_user.points + 5) # update_attributes assigns the attributes and saves
    redirect_to @wad    
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Error try again'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```